# accessing subtrees in jSON file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Hi all I hope you can help me with this one. My `JSON` file is structured like this:

```
[{
   {
    "link": {
       "title": "Applications"
    },
    "has_children": true,
    "subtree": [{
        "link": {
        "title": "Projects"
       },
       "subtree": [{
          "link": {
             "title": "WORK\/NEW YORK",
          }
       }]
     }]
   }
}]
```

Basically its a nav menu and it should be like this:

> Application => Projects => WORK/NEW YORK

I am iterating through the whole JSON file to get all the first objects. I have managed to access the first object and display "Application" with this code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {            
    var _title = (list[i].link.title);
    console.log(_title);     
    buildingMenuContent(_title);
}
```

Now, I wanna iterate through the first array index [0] and access its subtree first index[0] and finally the last subtree and its index[0] so i can be able to display:

> Application => Projects => WORK/NEW YORK

I used this code which got me to application => Projects but it did not iterate to get all of the first objects:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
         if (list[i].has_children) {
            for (var n = 0; n < list[i].subtree.length; n++) {
            var _subtitle = (list[i].subtree[n].link.title);
         }
       }    
    } 
 }
```

I dont know if I clarified this but i need loop through this array. I used a recursive for loop but it was too complicated to use it to manipulate the DOM after.

Comment: you need all possible path or just want first ?(index[0]), or i am complatly mistake ?!

Comment: I have updated the question @NozarSafari

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why recursion was not good for you? I don't think you can navigate this blindly and without recursion. If you really need to iterate this without recursion (again, why?), I'd iterate it with recursion to generate a map of the tree branches and lengths and then use this map to do a weird single loop... Are you sure you can't use recursion to loop it?

Comment: i am new to handling json files i am sorry. will you be able to provide e with a commented code please? I will be very thankful @FabioLolli

Comment: @ZyzzShembesh The JSON does not matter that much, this is just handling a normal object :) Anyway, posted my solution to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general advice, keep the schema of the objects/nodes in the JSON similar if you want to recursively iterate over them. It'll make your code easy and generic.

Doing it manually for every level is not recommended as others have said. What if another level comes up in the form of 4th subtree? 5th subtree? Would you keep writing code for that? I don't think so. It's better to come up with a recursive solution for such cases. To do this, the objects should have a similar structure so you can iterate over them, treating every object/node independently.

```
// Menu JSON structure
var menuList = [
    {
        "link": { "title": "Applications" },
        "has_children": true,
        "subtree": [
            {
                "link": { "title": "Projects" },
                "subtree": [
                    {
                        "link": { "title": "WORK\/NEW YORK" }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "link": { "title": "Operations" },
        "has_children": true,
        "subtree": [
            {
                "link": { "title": "Projects" },
                "subtree": [
                    {
                        "link": { "title": "WORK\/DALLAS" }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];

function printTree(list, isTopLevel) {
    let path = '';

    // Iterate all the nodes in the provided list array
    for ( var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i ) {
        path += list[i].link.title;

        // Process subtree if present
        // This condition can also be based on `has_children` property but since that isn't present across all nodes, I've used `subtree`
        if ( list[i].subtree && list[i].subtree.length > 0 ) {
            path += '=>'; // Add => only if current node has subtrees
            path += printTree(list[i].subtree, false); // Recursively add the subtree paths
        }

        // Only needed to insert new line after every parent node path has been added
        // Not really necessary
        if ( isTopLevel ) 
            path += '\n';
    }
    return path; // Return the path constructed at every node level 
}

console.log(printTree(menuList, true));


// Output:
// Applications=>Projects=>WORK/NEW YORK
// Operations=>Projects=>WORK/DALLAS
```

Notice the use of `subtree` property which is present across all nodes/objects. It can be used to detect recursive case as it's present across all nodes.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help i have marked your answer as the correct one because how how simple the code to understand

Comment: Dear @Kartik , I am trying now to use your function and it works great for logging the title and the sub thank you. Now what i want to do is to take the title and put it in a var then take its first sub put it in a var then if it there is a 3rd or 4th sub put each one in a var too. Hence I can use the vars to manipulate DOM and create a menu using ul and li. Basically , I want to turn this Output:

// Applications=>Projects=>WORK/NEW YORK
to 
`<ul>
<li>Applications</li>
<ul>
<li>Projects</i>
<ul>
<li> WORK/NEW YORK</i>
</ul>
</ul>
</ul>`

Comment: any ideas with what i want to achieve??

Comment: any ideas with what i want to achieve??

Comment: Hi @ZyzzShembesh. What you can do is hack the `printTree` function to return an HTML string of lists instead of printing the pattern with '=>'. I have made some changes with more sub-lists in the JSON. Also, the string returned by JS code is given as `innerHTML` to a DOM node. Take a look- http://jsbin.com/sorurov/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Also, the approach of making a `var` from every menu item would not be very efficient. You'll end up using `eval` to create a dynamic variable which would be a really bad implementation.

Comment: thats great man i will check it and get back to you.. how many years did you require to get this knowledge?

Comment: thats great man i will check it and get back to you.. how many years did you require to get this knowledge?

Answer (score 0):

first your inputs are wrong !!! syntax error ,
second recursion  is only way because u dont know how level u must go down

```
var q =[
 {
    "link": {
        "title": "Applications"
            },
    "has_children": true,
    "subtree": [{
            "link": {
                "title": "Projects"
            },
            "subtree": [{
                    "link": {
                        "title": "WORK\/NEW YORK",
                            }}]
                     }]
  }]


function find_child(json)
//a function move down until error happen (last level of json)
  {
      result ="" // this varible hold result
    try // just to avoid if!!! at last level of json it will go to catch and end this loop
    {
        if(json.link.title) // check this field is in json ?
            result += json.link.title
        result += "=>" +find_child( json.subtree[0]) /* call again with {
        "link": {
            "title": "Projects"
        },
        "subtree": [{
                "link": {
                    "title": "WORK\/NEW YORK",
                        }}]
                 } and second type with nex child at forth time it cause error and return*/

    }
    catch (e)
    {
    }
    return result
  }

  print(find_child(q[0],""))
```

result = Applications=>Projects=>WORK/NEW YORK

Comment: is it enough? or need more ?

Comment: but what if i have many children? this is hard coded  "result += "=>" +find_child( json.subtree[0])" i need it to loop @nozarsafari

Comment: its imposible with loop i can change it to find all children or call this function in loop , but for go deep in json u need recursion , this is two difrent thing, first check all children in a level(can do by `for` easily edit in my code) second go next level (it need to be recursion  ), if your json always have three level u can use loop for going deep too

Comment: thank you very much for your help. yes mine is 3 levels but will use recursive just incase

Answer (score 0):

```
let tree = {}; //your parsed JSON here

const loopTree = (tree, subTreePropName, resultAccumulator) => {
  if (tree) {
    if (tree[subTreePropName]) {
      resultAccumulator += tree[subTreePropName].map((subtree) => loopTree(subtree, subTreePropName, resultAccumulator));
    }
    return resultAccumulator + tree.link.title;
  }
  return '';
}

let result = loopTree(tree, 'subtree', '');
```

I did not test this, but it should work... Explanation of how loopTree works:

`if (tree)` check if the function was called with an undefined item. In case this is false (or null, or undefined - means this was called with an empty object), return an empty string. Otherwise, let's loop the tree!

`if (tree[subTreePropName])` checks if the current tree we are visiting has a subtree property. If not, it's a leaf. Return resultAccumulator + own text. Otherwise, it's a branch, let's loop it!

`resultAccumulator += tree[...].map(...)` this is the heart of the recursion. It says - for each item in the current tree's subtree, loop it and add to our result its result.

`return resultAccumulator + tree.link.title;` is the line closing the recursion. It returns current result + own title.

`let result = loopTree(tree, 'subtree', '')` is where we effectively execute the loop. We're saying, loop the tree `tree`, looking for childs in the property named `'subtreee'`, and add the results of each item to an empty string. The final result is set to the result variable.

Does this make sense?
Is this what you need, or did I miss some conditional somewhere?

If you want to take this one step further, you can pass an additional `processValues` value in the function to map specific tree items... EX:

```
let processValues = (treeItem) => {
  return treeItem.link.title
}
```

And then

```
let tree = {}; //your parsed JSON here

const loopTree = (tree, subTreePropName, resultAccumulator, itemMapper) => {
  if (tree) {
    if (tree[subTreePropName]) {
      resultAccumulator += tree[subTreePropName].map((subtree) => loopTree(subtree, subTreePropName, resultAccumulator, itemMapper));
    }
    return resultAccumulator + itemMapper(tree);
  }
  return '';
}

let result = loopTree(tree, 'subtree', '', processValues);
```

This will allow to pass a function as the 4th argument. This function should receive a tree item, and return its related value.

This way you can add all your conditional and operations in that processValues function, and the loop stays clean.